# _switch_user doesn't work

Tags: security, symfony

I'm trying to use the `switch_user` technique described in the Symfony2 [security docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I browse to `http://myurl.com/foo?_switch_user=bar`, the page gets refreshed, but I'm still logged in as the admin user, not `bar`.

Here's the relevant part of my `app/config/security.yml`:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: VNNPressboxBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login: ~
        logout: ~
        anonymous: ~
        switch_user: true
```

Any ideas as to what the issue is?

Comment: Have you recently changed the role_hierarchy and/or your role on the db? You could try logging out and back in again to refresh your session object.

Comment: Yes, I had recently changed those things, but logging out and logging back in, unfortunately, didn't make it work. I even cleared my Symfony cache and restarted my server.

Comment: Are you using a custom user setup?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but I think the answer is not really. I stuck to the defaults as closely as possible.

Comment: I think the `ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH` should be in an array `[ROLE.....SWITCH]`. Don't know if that would do it though.

Comment: Good call. Unfortunately that didn't seem to change anything. Interestingly, I do know for a fact that the user as whom I'm logged in does have `ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH`, via an if statement in my view. So that's not an issue.

Comment: Are you sure to give a username in `_switch_user=bar`? Does the user is active? Can you look at the debug bar and search if there is a query to fetch the given user? That would indicate that the security layer is trying to do his work or not.

Comment: Yes, I gave a username and the user is active. I actually happen not to have a debug bar for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try clearing symfony cache? I had some unexplainable issues too that were fixed just by clearing it. It doesn't hurt to try :)

**Update:** After reading question comments, by the lack of debug bar, I can guess that you might be in production environment. This could be the source of your trouble.
Try clearing cache and switching to dev environment by running this:

```
php app/console --env=dev cache:clear
```

Update2: Are you accessing your app via app_dev.php file ?

Comment: I had cleared my cache before, and yes, I was accessing my app via `app_dev.php`, but maybe I needed to explicitly include `--env=dev` in order for it to really work. It doesn't seem like that should have been the case, but in any case, it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think that was just the case.

When you entered to the production environment Symfony2 cached your config files and it didn't read them from original locations anymore so your changes weren't actually changing anything. By switching it back to "dev" environment you forced it to read config files again and cache new versions. While you are in dev environment Symfony will automaticly read config files if they are changed but in production you have to clear the cache and force it to do it manually.I guessed you are in production environment by your comment.You should see debug bar now

Comment: The lack of debug toolbar can also be caused by a badly rendered html.
if you don't include `<html><body></body></html>` in the response the profiler wont intercept the request.

try to return `new Response('');` from a controller.

also, the `cache:clear` command clears the cache by default for the dev environment if no --env option was passed.
and each environment has its own cache directory in `/cache` at times I had to forcefully delete the folders and run `cache:warmup` to correct problems.